# How to display standard up/down controls in iOS toolbar

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, interface-builder

I was wondering if Apple provides standard controls for the up/down arrow keys for the toolbar? All the other familiar buttons are present in Interface Builder, but not the arrow keys.

[image: arrow controls]

Is there a way to show them programmatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no public built-in control to display such a button. You can easily enough create your own, though, with a UISegmentedControl and `momentary` set to YES (put it in the toolbar using `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:...]`, of course).

You can probably use the Unicode characters U+25B2 for ▲ and U+25BC for ▼, or you can use appropriate images.